# Sharing code between two almost identical widgets PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have two widgets that are almost identical, the difference is one of them has an extra button. Right now there are a bunch of methods in both which are exactly the same. What strategies do I have to share code between them? Is subclassing the best alternative here? Someday I may want to alter the superclass with functionality that wont exist in the subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use regular inheritance.

```
class A(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.x = 1

        self._initProperties() # Special method for changing values with inheritance
    # end Constructor

    def _initProperties(self):
        """Initialize special inheritance properties."""
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
    # end _initProperties

    def do_something(self):
        return self.x

class B(A):
    # def __init__(self):
    #     super().__init__()
    # 
    #     self.y = 2
    # # Because we have _initProperties that will happen at the appropriate time we don't
    # really need __init__. Just use _initProperties.
    # However, I would still use __init__. I just commented it out as an example.

    def _initProperties(self):
        """Initialize special inheritance properties.
        Note: We did not call super, so we are not using the parents _initProperties methods.
              We are overriding the parent method.
        """
        self.y = 2
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
    # end _initProperties

    def do_something(self):
        return super().do_something() + self.y
```

The alternate option is to create a regular object class mixin.

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.x = 1

    def do_something(self):
        return self.x


class A(MyMixin, QtGui.QWidget):
    pass

class B(MyMixin, QtGui.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self)
        super().__init__()

        self.y = 2

    def do_something(self):
        return super().do_something() + self.y
```

Python supports multiple inheritance. With this approach class A can be a QWidget while class B can be something different like a QGroupBox

Comment: Inheritance is leading to a weird error. So both classes have a ui file assicoated with them. The subclass is appropriately calling it's ui file. However, there's a method inside this class (retranslateUi) which is present in both ui files. The subclass however calls the super class retranslateUi, which messes up the Ui later. Renaming retranslateUi to something else solves that issue, but I wouldn't like to do that every time I change my Ui. Any Idea how I can solve this?

EDIT: Never mind, I changed the order of the subclassing and it's working now

Comment: I edited my answer to show other things you can do with inheritance for sensitive variables and properties that you may not want in sub classes.

Comment: Yeah I'm basically doing that. Calling the setup inside setupUi method. Why do you use an _ though? Is there any special reason for that?

Comment: the _ is just a python thing that lets programmers know that it should be a private method. Python doesn't really have private methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use subclassing. It is a very basic strategy of OOP.
This intro gives a nice overview: http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/
But you might find many other sources as well.